# How do I delete my Realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I made a free Minecraft Realm and I would like to use my world for something else. How do I delete the Realm and get my world back?

Answer (score 5):

> How do I delete the Realm?

First of all, you cannot delete your Realm, but you can change the world, or you can close the realm.

> How do I get my world back?

If you want the world for just single-player or you want the file back, do the following.

1. Go to the **Configure Realm** menu.
2. Click on **World Backups**.
3. Either click on **Download Latest**, or click on the arrow on any backup you want.
4. Finally, it should be under **Single Player**.

   - Also, if you want the file of the world go to `%Appdata%\.minecraft\saves`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that you can delete Realms pretty easily.

Go to Configure realm -> Subscription and click 'Delete Realm'. That's it.

Comment: This is the correct solution. However, it's lacking information. The button only appears once your realm expires. This can cause others to think that this answer is incorrect when it's not.

Comment: I cancelled my realm a month ago but now it says it's going to renew in 2 days!!!  There's no delete button, only an "extend subscription" button.  Why can't they make this as easy to cancel as it is to set up. Grrrr.

Answer (score 0):

You may delete your realm once it expires by going to the **Subscription** settings of your realm and pressing **Delete Realm**.

Make sure you have cancelled your subscription and downloaded your world using the **Download latest** button found in your settings before you delete your realm.

However, if you are creating a new realm or want a different world, it is always recommended that you use your current realm and not delete it, and instead change worlds or reset it.